# How do I create a custom toast message that displays random messages

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

xml for the button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button001"
    android:text="@string/text_7"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

I want to display messages **("Hello", "Bonjour", "Good day", "Lets Go")** as toasts randomly.
The java code for the toast function:

```
 Button button001;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        button001 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kabutton);
        button001.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] {"Hello","Bonjour!","Good day","Lets Go"};
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),[String],Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your string array and then get a random index every time you click the button.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String[] randomStrings = new String[] {"Hello","Bonjour!","Good day","Lets Go"};
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),randomStrings[new Random().nextInt(randomStrings.length - 1)],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom view for the Toast message using `setView()` method. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView).
For the random, you Java's Random class `nextInt()` method and have those strings as list and using the int that random gave you to access one at a time.

Comment: I want the toast to display random messages when the button is pressed